# Wrap RABL response object into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rabl

Given the following code:

```
object false

node(:display){"comments"}
node :payload do
  @comments.map do |c|
    { 
      :id => c.id,
      :content => c.content
    }
  end
end
```

Resulting in following output:

```
{
    display: "comments",
    payload: [
        {
            id: 35,
            content: "A nice one"
        },
        {
            id: 40,
            content: "Supah dupa"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to wrap the output in an array, any ideas on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the entire response? I'm not sure what you mean about wrapping the output. Could you provide the example of the output you're looking for?

If you're looking to have everything in an array, wrapping them in an empty node should do the trick:

```
object false

node do
  node(:display){"comments"}
  node :payload do
    @comments.map do |c|
      { 
        :id => c.id,
        :content => c.content
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I simply want the output wrapped on an array like: `[ { ... } ]`